# How do i get a field data from template and use it before adding to database?

Tags: python, django

How can i capture and use the data of specific field, that was entered into my formset(on template), before saving it to database?

I can get the "hour" value via .save(commit=False) because the value didn't change, but how can I capture the value that changed ( for example, data from formset.work_amount after user enters it)?

**Edit 2.**    I forgot to mention i'm using a model formset

```
AuthorFormSet = modelformset_factory(CalendGraph, fields=('project_name','work_name','work_amount','unit_name','employee_name','hours','days','approve_need','approve_time','calendar_start','calendar_end',),extra =1, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        new_formset= formset.save(commit=False)
        if formset.is_valid():
            worka = int(request.POST.get('work_amount') #wrong, how can i get the work amount data from formset?
            new_formset.hours= worka*8
            new_formset.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect("/calend-graph-1/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't quite make sense: a formset contains multiple forms, so you will have multiple values for work_amount. You get each value from the `cleaned_data` dict of each form in the formset, so you could get all the work_amount values with:

```
[form.cleaned_data['work_amount'] for form in formset]
```

Comment: But doesn't a form adds to formset only after i .save() it? I'm new to django, so i might sound stupid, but when i fill all fields at template and press submit button, the if start to work, right? So can't i just use a work_amount i get from template before saving it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would think that. The formset contains all the forms that have been submitted, and if they are valid, they will have a `cleaned_data` dict. Nothing to do with saving.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, i actually understood this way and it is better, and if you don't bother answering one more question: can i use this code:   for form in formset:
                form.cleaned_data['hours']= form.cleaned_data['work_amount']*8'

Comment: also can i use cleaned_data outside of `is_valid()?`

Comment: I forgot to mention i'm using model formset, not just a formset

Comment: You can only use `cleaned_data` once you have called `is_valid()`, because that's what triggers the validation and populates the clean data. It makes no difference if you are using model or non-model formset.